# Are there any resources where I might be able to find post sound DAW screenshots for well known film and tv content?

Tags: editing, sound

first time poster and budding sound designer here, I often find that while watching great content that I'd love to know exactly how the sound was edited for a particular scene, particularly in regards to how its layered, mixed, crossfaded etc. A screenshot of the actual session would be invaluable to learning how exactly the sounds were crafted together. The only thing I've found which comes vaguely close is a YouTube video where Richard King discusses the Paris scene, and a screengrab of the Pro Tools session plays in real time with the actual scene.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yebo and welcome :-)

One site I do really love myself, is Soundworks collection. They have a vast collection of purely sound-oriented BTS material, and update very regularly!

http://soundworkscollection.com/